# Java heap analysis with OQL/VisualVM: find path from indirect referrer to referee?

Tags: java, heap-memory, visualvm, oql

I am trying to find the first path found from an object to some indirect referree.

The following code is what I came up with:

```
var debug = [];

//set referrer and target
var referrerObj = heap.findObject("815262352");
var targetObj = heap.findObject("815441600");

//prepare refer obj
var pathToTarget = getShortestReferPath([referrerObj], targetObj, 6);
[allocTrace(pathToTarget), debug];

//sets the shortest reference path from referrer to target
function getShortestReferPath(referPath, targetObj, maxDepth, depth) {
    depth = (typeof(depth) != "undefined") ? depth : 1;

    //get the last referrer for further processing
    var lastReferrer = referPath[referPath.length-1];

    //check every referee of the referrer
    var dirReferees = referees(lastReferrer);
    while (dirReferees.hasMoreElements()) {
        var dirReferee = dirReferees.nextElement();

        //if this referee is our target, set the path and return
        if (identical(dirReferee, targetObj)) {
            referPath.push(dirReferee);
            return referPath;
        }
    }

    //none of these is our target, so check the next depth if it is not too high
    if (depth < maxDepth) {
        var dirRefereesTwo = referees(lastReferrer);
        while (dirRefereesTwo.hasMoreElements()) {
            var dirRefereeTwo = dirRefereesTwo.nextElement();

            //set this referee as our last item
            var newReferPath = referPath.slice();
            newReferPath.push(dirRefereeTwo);
            var referPathTest = getShortestReferPath(newReferPath, targetObj, maxDepth, depth + 1);
            if (referPathTest != null) return referPathTest;
        }
    }

    //return the current path
    return null;
}
```

I run this bit of Javascript inside VisualVM's OQL query window.

It is supposed to go through all referees of the referrerObj one by one up to a maximum depth, at which it should look to the next referee level if the target has not been found yet.

For some reason however, the code seems to stop execution after following the possible paths of the first direct referee of the initial referrer passed.

It looks like the second while loop is never completing. I am not getting any error code, but simply that nothing is returned.

Does anyone have any clue why this could happen? If someone else could run this in VisualVM and report his/her findings, that'd be great.

Thanks.